# How to whitelist a specific regex in addition to unit-whitelist?

Tags: stylelint

I would like to allow `\1px\` usages but not any other pixel values. This is the rule currently:

`"unit-whitelist": [["%", "vh","vw"], {
   "message": "Please use rem() for size units"
 }],`

Answer (score 0):

This is not currently an available option in stylelint. You can only ignore *units* as a whole, and not specific values of units such as allowing `1px` but disallowing `5px`

You could create a new issue at stylelint to discuss this further with the stylelint team at:

> https://github.com/stylelint/stylelint/issues/new

Answer (score 0):

Meanwhile, stylelint supports this kind of rules:

- [declaration-property-value-blacklist](https://stylelint.io/user-guide/rules/declaration-property-value-blacklist)
- [declaration-property-value-whitelist](https://stylelint.io/user-guide/rules/declaration-property-value-whitelist)

It's been shipped in [version 4.3](https://github.com/stylelint/stylelint/releases/tag/4.3.0) early 2016 as `property-value-[black|white]list` and [renamed to the current rule names in early 2017](https://github.com/stylelint/stylelint/issues/551#issuecomment-294828924).

---

If you want to allow only *em*, *rem* and `1px`, you can achieve this with the following rules:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "declaration-property-unit-whitelist": {
      "/.*/": ["em", "rem", "px"]
    },
    "declaration-property-value-blacklist": {
      "/.*/": ["(\\d+[1]+px|[^1]+px)"]
    }
}
```

- The first rule has a whitelist of all units you want to allow, plus the *px* as we want to allow `1px` specifically.
- The last rule disallows any values other than *1* for *px* units. It also disallows values like `11px` and `21px`.
  Be care careful that this will also match `content: 'This item has a height of 9px.'` and disallows this.
- Both rules match all properties. You might want to scope them by changing the regex `/.*/` to a more specific one, like `/^border.*/`